LazyColumn Recomposed when selected to pass url to AsyncImage
New to Jetpack compose, can someone explain why when i select an item in LazyRow and pass that url to the Image it will recomposed the whole row again? HOw should i be using the movieSelector variable?
@Composable
fun MovieHorizontalCarousel(viewModel: MovieViewModel = MovieViewModel()) {
    val movies: LazyPagingItems<Movie> = viewModel.movies.collectAsLazyPagingItems()

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
    ) {

        val movieSelector = remember { mutableStateOf("") }
        Carousel(
            movies = movies,
            onMovieSelected = { url -> movieSelector.value = url },
            Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(100.dp)
        )

        MoviePreview(
            movieSelector.value,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .weight(1f)
        )
    }

}

@Composable
fun MoviePreview(url: String,
                 modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    AsyncImage(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Purple40),
        model = url,
        contentDescription = "Preview"
    )
}

@Composable
fun Carousel(movies: LazyPagingItems<Movie>,
             onMovieSelected: (String) -> Unit,
             modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {

    LazyRow(
        modifier = modifier
            .wrapContentSize()
            .background(Purple80),
        //horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        items (
            count = movies.itemCount,
            key = { index -> movies[index]?.id ?: index }
            //key = movies.itemKey{ item -> item.id }
        ) { index ->
            movies[index]?.let {
                MovieCarouselItem(movie = it,
                                  onMovieSelected = onMovieSelected)
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MovieCarouselItem (movie: Movie,
                       onMovieSelected: (String) -> Unit,
                       modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {

    AsyncImage(
        modifier = modifier
            .size(81.dp)
            .clickable {
                onMovieSelected("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500${movie.posterPath}")
            },
        model = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500${movie.posterPath}",
        contentDescription = "Movie Thumbnail" ,
        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
        placeholder = painterResource(id = R.drawable.photo)
    )
}

I am trying to display the image that the user selected from the lazyrow, it updated the image but also recomposed the list of movies.

Would assume that the issue is that the entire column is the closest scope that's restartable, see: https://www.jetpackcompose.app/articles/donut-hole-skipping-in-jetpack-compose
Just to test that, try wrapping the MoviePreview (in MovieHorizontalCarousel) with a box or something and see what recomposes then

Move the selection state outside the Column :
@Composable
fun MovieHorizontalCarousel(viewModel: MovieViewModel = MovieViewModel()) {
    val movies: LazyPagingItems<Movie> = viewModel.movies.collectAsLazyPagingItems()

    // Hoist state to avoid unnecessary recomposition of Carousel
    var selectedMovieUrl by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        Carousel(
            movies = movies,
            onMovieSelected = { url -> selectedMovieUrl = url },
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(100.dp)
        )

        MoviePreview(
            url = selectedMovieUrl,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .weight(1f)
        )
    }
}

